# Input binding stealing input from textbox

Tags: wpf

In my main widow I have some commands mapped to 1, 2, 3, 4. When I press those keys in a textbox, those commands get executed instead of 1/2/3/4 being added to the textbox. What is the best way to ensure typing those keys inside the textbox will be adding those text instead of executing the commands?

Here is a sample program and when I press '1', the executed logic runs and '1' is not added to the textbox. Any other keys work like they should.

```
<Window x:Class="TextboxWithCommands.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.InputBindings>  
        <KeyBinding Command="Open" Key="D1"/>    
    </Window.InputBindings>

    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Open" 
                        Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"
                        CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox/>
    </Grid>
</Window>



 private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add some code as to how you're commands are implemented?

Comment: One somewhat hacky (and untested) way to do it might be to check who has focus in your CanExecute handler and return false if it's a textbox.

Comment: @MattBurland Sorry for stealing your idea, I didn't saw your suggestion. However your suggestion works perfectly, and it's not hacky if the event handles `CANExecute` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute( object sender , CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e )
{
  e.CanExecute = !(e.ContinueRouting = (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement( this ) is TextBox));
}
```

Comment: It works but one thing I would like to add is that its the e.ContinueRouting that allows the text to be pass to the textbox. The e.CanExecute does not effect if the textbox see the text or not.