# KeyGesture doesn't support only one key

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I want to create my custom command and to hook it up to some key.
I am using KeyGesture in code behing for that purpose , and in the constructor I see that I can pass only one key (without modifierKey) but at runtime I get exception , saying :

```
"'None + Q' key and modifier combination is not supported for KeyGesture"
```

I just don't understand why there is a constructor for only one key and still I need to set also the modifier key combination in order not to get the exception.

Comment: Not a duplicate (since this question is specifically asking about KeyGestures) but the following answer will help circumvent this problem in most use cases (by not using KeyGestures): http://stackoverflow.com/a/8251097/4961688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasted from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522894.aspx):

> In most cases, a KeyGesture must be associated with one or more
>   ModifierKeys. The exceptions to this rule are the function keys and
>   the numeric keypad keys, which can be a valid KeyGesture by
>   themselves.

The problem with "normal" keys is to distinguish an actual button press from a shortcut. For example if you have a textbox, you can't use a command with the gesture Q to do something differently than inserting the character Q. If you want something like that use the KeyDown/Up commands and your own command invocation.

Comment: didn't think about the textbox :) . You'r right , that's really makes sence :) thanks for your answer!

Comment: Incorrect, downvoted. The solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251043/create-a-simple-unmodified-key-binding-in-wpf

Comment: @Benlitz: It's not really incorrect. The question asks about KeyGestures and those do not support this. The linked question solves the problem in 99% of the use cases however (by avoiding KeyGestures in the first place).

Comment: @Benlitz is correct.  There are many valid cases where you want to use single key bindings.  The solution to not having a textbox eat user input is to use the continue routing ability as in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741700/input-binding-stealing-input-from-textbox

Comment: Look at an application named "PDF Anotator". They use a single key to switch between their tools without any modifier, yet they still can differentiate between shortcuts and typing.